# Javascript object behaving mysteriously in node.js but works fine in jsbin

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a mysterious looking problem in node.js javascript. I am logging `row` object which looks like { 'email': '15', surveyLink: 'hghgh', name: 'LOO' } in node.js. You can see that email has quotes around it. I am having problem dealing with this key. I tried the same code in jsbin and it is working fine but it causing a problem in node.js javascript. https://jsbin.com/curirikoxo/edit?html,console,output
I am trying to make changes to an html in such a way that for every occuerence of `{{+key+}}` I want to change it to value of object for that key. It is working fine in jsbin but when I am running same code in node.js javascript, {{email}} in html is not being replaced by its value. Can you tell me what could be the reason for it ?

I have tried things like `JSON.stringify()` the object and then again `JSON.parse()` the object but no effect of that happens in the result. I felt the key `email` might have quotes around it  like this `'email'` while using key in `html.replace(new RegExp(match, 'g'), row[key])` which may be causing the problem so I checked `key.indexOf('\'')` but the logs were giving `-1`. I have tried many other things and I have gone mad and feeling frustrated for this silly problem.

```
  function replaceVariablesWithDataInTemplate(html,row){
  let keys=Object.keys(row);
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row)));
  for (var key of keys){
  let match="{{"+key+"}}";
 console.log(html.indexOf(key));
      console.log(Object.keys(row).forEach(key => { console.log(key, '-', 
      key.charAt(0), ':', key.charCodeAt(0)); })); //update-3
  html=html.replace(new RegExp(match, 'g'), row[key]);
  }
```

Can you tell me why this is happening in node.js javascript but is working fine in jsbin ? Also can you suggest me some ways to overcome it ?

Update 1:This row object is being received from firestore. I can't find a reason as to why only email key has quotes around it in row object. Also I would like to share all the rows in firestore are being written from csv file stored on firebase storage and is parsed using `papaparse` module. This email is the first column of csv previously `name` was the first column in csv and at that time name key was causing the problem. When I update the document from firestore console by deleting the `email` key and write it back again with same value my function gives correct results and in both cases the way `email` key looks in firestore is same i.e. quotes are not shown on `email` field in firestore console.

**Update-2:** I am adding a screen shot of how the logs look before and after deleting and readding `email` key with same value below in cloud firestore.

[image]

**Update-3:**

```
email -  : 65279
surveyLink - s : 115
name - n : 110
undefined
email -  : 65279
surveyLink - s : 115
name - n : 110
undefined
email -  : 65279
surveyLink - s : 115
name - n : 110
undefined
```

Comment: Can you post your full `.js` you're using in Node? Sounds like its implementation is different from the code on the jsbin

Comment: That js is whole backend in itself as I am using firebase cloud functions and this html and row are coming from firebase database, you will have to go way back in the code as to how they were first written onto firebase database but I would like to share one mysterious thing there as well. The function gives correct responses after I delete the `email` key in firebase database console and write the same field again with same value and the code in node.js also start giving correct results.

Comment: I can't find a reason as to why only `email` key has quotes around it in `row` object. Also I would like to share all the rows in firebase database are being written from csv file stored on firebase storage and is parsed using `papaparse` module. This email is the first column of csv previously `name` was the first column in csv and at that time `name` key was causing the problem.

Comment: You say your object "looks like this". What does "looks like this" mean in this context? If you are *declaring* it with code that looks like that, then your key is `email`. But if `console.log()` is showing that, then you have quotation marks as part of your object key: `"email"` and that is almost certainly the source of the difference in behavior.

Comment: @Trott I am doing `console.log()` to get `{ 'email': '15', surveyLink: 'hghgh', name: 'LOO' }`. Do you know any way to remove these quotes from `email` key because I have tried `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row)))` and the quotes are still present, the only way which I have been able to find which is giving correct result i.e. `{{email}}` gets replaced with value of `row.email` is by deleting the key and writing this field again in firestore console.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Can you throw some light as to why row seems to be doing fine after deleting and writing again the `email` field in firestore console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem is with malformed source of data, CSV file in your case.
And so, in your database `email` key starts with the BOM character.

The easiest workaround will be to "clean up" objects after fetching them from database.

For example you can use function:

```
function cleanUp(obj) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    const cleanKey = key.charCodeAt(0) === 0xFEFF ? key.substr(1) : key;
    acc[cleanKey] = value;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

You can use it like:

```
function replaceVariablesWithDataInTemplate(html,obj) {
  const row = cleanUp(obj);
  let keys=Object.keys(row);
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row)));

  for (var key of keys) {
    let match="{{"+key+"}}";
    console.log(html.indexOf(key));
    html = html.replace(new RegExp(match, 'g'), row[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly cleaning up the object doesn't work either. Still on logging the object there are quotes around email key and I am unable to replace `{{email}}` with its value in `row` object. @quadreex

Comment: @KartikWatwani Can you please add the following code at the begining of your replace function: ```Object.keys(row).forEach(key => {
  console.log(key, '-', key.charAt(0), ':', key.charCodeAt(0));
});```, and paste the result of its execution as an update to the question?

Comment: I have updated the question before calling replace function as replace is not a function created by me it is present in String prototype.

Comment: @KartikWatwani 65279 is [zero-width no-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm). I'll update my answer to properly remove it.

Comment: Love you. I wouldn't have been able to find that invisible character ever.